# Delete specific text from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to delete  specific text   which starts with @ if the user try to delete some characters from  it 
I try this code

```
mBinding.questionEdtHelp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                mPreviousLength = charSequence.length();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
              if (i1 - i2 == 1) {
                    if ( charSequence.toString().charAt(i) == '@') {
                        mBinding.questionEdtHelp.getText().delete(i , i1);
                    }
                }

            }
```

can any one help me ?

Comment: What is an error? this code run perfectly or not?

Comment: If code is not working perfectly share your error log.

Comment: i don'tget any error but i can't delete the specific text wich start with @